# Update shiny DT based on editable cells user input

Tags: r, shiny, dt

A small example shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("blah"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           DT::DTOutput('ex_table')
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$ex_table <- DT::renderDataTable(mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% mutate(blah = cyl + 2), 
                                           selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you run that it looks like:
[image]

You can edit the cells since I added `editable = TRUE` within `renderDataTable()`.

My table that feeds the datatable has the line:

```
mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% mutate(blah = cyl + 2)
```

So feature 'blah' should always be whatever is in cyl + 2. In the screen shot I added 10,000, so desired output would be for the datatable to update to show 10,002 after hitting enter.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow these [examples](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/).
Try :

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("blah"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      DT::DTOutput('modtable'),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% mutate(blah = cyl + 2)
  
  output$modtable <- DT::renderDT(data, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy('modtable')

  observeEvent(input$modtable_cell_edit, {
    info = input$modtable_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    data <<- editData(data, info)
    if(j==1){data[i,j+1]<<-as.numeric(data[i,j])+2}
    replaceData(proxy, data, resetPaging = FALSE) 
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]