# DT with editable cells error with observeEvent() editData() "Warning: Error in split.default: first argument must be a vector"

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am attempting to create a shiny app with editable cells where the underlying data frame updates depending on user input. I asked a [similar question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834508/update-shiny-dt-based-on-editable-cells-user-input/63837500#63837500) and was pointed to [this link](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/).

My app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("blah"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            DT::DTOutput('ex_table'),
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    example_data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0, 1) %>% round) %>% mutate(y = x + 1)
    output$ex_table <- DT::renderDT(example_data, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
    
    # from https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/
    observeEvent(input$ex_table_cell_edit, {
        example_data <<- editData(example_data, input$ex_table, 'ex_table', rownames = FALSE)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This app loads when you press run in rstudio. But when trying to edit a cell in column x, the app crashes with error message 'Warning: Error in split.default: first argument must be a vector'.

This is the problem code block:

```
# from https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/
observeEvent(input$ex_table_cell_edit, {
    example_data <<- editData(example_data, input$ex_table, 'ex_table', rownames = FALSE)
})
```

Screens:
[image]

The app loads up fine. Y is always x + 1 due to the data frame definition:

```
example_data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0, 1) %>% round) %>% mutate(y = x + 1)
```

When a user edits the x column, I wouldlike the y column to update to be whatever x is plus one:
[image]

When I press enter, desired behavior is to have y = 101.

Per the link suggested, https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/, I'd prefer to use `editData()` as opposed to what was provided in my previous post, because `editData()` approach looks simpler and more readable.

But when I try it my shiny app always crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing program works fine if you put `rownames=FALSE` in `output$ex_table`.  However, it only allows you to edit table cells. If you still want to maintain the dependency `y=x+1`, you need to define like @Waldi did in his answer earlier. Also, once you modify, you need to feed it back to the output via `replaceData()` of Proxy or define a `reactiveValues` object as shown below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("blah"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput('ex_table'),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  example_data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0, 1) %>% round) %>% mutate(y = x + 1)
  DF1$data <- example_data
  output$ex_table <- renderDT(DF1$data, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$ex_table_cell_edit, {
    
    info = input$ex_table_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col + 1  ## offset by 1 

    example_data <<- editData(example_data, input$ex_table_cell_edit, 'ex_table', rownames = FALSE)
    if(j==1){example_data[i,j+1]<<-as.numeric(example_data[i,j])+1}  ###  y = x + 1 dependency
    
    DF1$data <- example_data
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]