# How to fix editable DT::datatable throwing: "Error in split.default: first argument must be a vector"

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to make a module that accepts a data frame and produces an editable datatable out of it. This worked until I made the module able to accept multiple edits by making the following change:

```
editTable <- reactive({
        datatable(
          reactives$input,
          #editable = T                      #PREVIOUS (working fine)
          editable = list(target = "all"),   #NEW (problem-causing)
          rownames = F
        )
      })
```

Once the code labelled `#NEW` is included, clicking `labelDo` (in this case "Edit") causes the app to crash with this error message:

```
Warning: Error in split.default: first argument must be a vector
```

The closest problem I could find to this one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838479/dt-with-editable-cells-error-with-observeevent-editdata-warning-error-in-s) . This user's problem is the same but mine is not solved (as theirs allegedly is) by putting `rownames = FALSE` into their `datatable()` equivalent of the snippet above.

Please go ahead and run the following module and app together and attempt to edit one of the numbers in the table. Click 'edit' and you will get the same result.

**Module:**

```
editrUI <- function(id, labelDo, labelUndo) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    dataTableOutput(ns("out")),
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("do"),
      label = labelDo
    ),
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("undo"),
      label = labelUndo
    )
  )
}

editrServer <- function(id, dataFrame) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      
      reactives <- reactiveValues()
      
      reactives$input <- NULL
        
      observe({
        reactives$input <- dataFrame
      })
      
      
      editTable <- reactive({
        datatable(
          reactives$input,
          #editable = T                    #old
          editable = list(target = "all"), #new
          rownames = F
        )
      })
      
      output$out <- renderDataTable(
        editTable()
      )
      
      observeEvent(input$do , {
        reactives$input <<- editData(reactives$input, input$out_cell_edit, rownames = F) 
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$undo , {
        reactives$input <- dataFrame
      })
      
      return(reactive({reactives$input}))
    }
  )
}
```

**App:**

```
library(shiny)

source(
  #source of module
)

a <- 1:5
df <- tibble(a, a*2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    editrUI(id = "id", labelDo = "Edit", labelUndo = "Undo")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    editrServer(id = "id", dataFrame = df)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I can reproduce exact same issue with `#old` code

Comment: Interesting, I just tried again and the `#old` code still runs just fine. Why do you think this is?

Comment: @HubertL , forgot to tag In above comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this error is caused when `input$out_cell_edit` is NULL (no cell has been edited).

You can fix it with `req(input$out_cell_edit)` that will cancel the event in case `input$out_cell_edit` is NULL.

Also you don't need to use `<<-` to assign to the reactiveValues.

```r
      observeEvent(input$do , {
        req(input$out_cell_edit)
        reactives$input <- editData(reactives$input, input$out_cell_edit, rownames = F) 
      })
```

Comment: thankyou, this solves the initial problem but unfortunately the app still doesn't work. When you click "Edit", the changes that you make do not save. They disappear if you reorder the table for example. Any idea how to fix this?